# Requests per second comparision in http versus cron job on GAE

Tags: http, google-app-engine, cron

I wrote a program to send mails from GAE. It can be run in two ways:-

1. as a http request
2. as a scheduled cron job (by writing job desc. in cron.yaml)

Requests per second for the latter case is almost half the former.

[image: screen shot from app's dashboard]

Why could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: It's impossible to say without more details - what's the code for each? What logs show up in the request logs? The most obvious answer, though, is that the second request is for favicon.ico.

Comment: my (python) code reads 400 email ids from a file which is available on gae itself and shoots them all a mail each.

Comment: That's nice, but it's not code, and you haven't provided any details that would allow us to distinguish your app from scores of apps that don't experience this. The simplest explanation is still `favicon.ico`.

Comment: The logs say that `favicon.ico` is requested. That explains why the number of requests are doubled. Isn't there a way to avoid it?

Comment: There is no way to stop it; read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867206/how-to-prevent-the-browser-from-asking-for-the-favicon/4867228#4867228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, there are 2 request instead of one when using HTTP requests. All modern browsers attempt to retrieve the favicon.ico file from the server, and, even if it does not exist, it is counted in the graph.

Comment: @Nick I'm invoking a function by appending it to app's url and attaching the necessary get parameters. e.g. `appid.appspot.com/sendMail?parameter=filName.txt`. I directly type this URL into the address bar. Doesn't this ensure that the browser doesn't look for favicon.ico?

Comment: No, it still looks for the favicon.