# Facvicon in Asp.net (Website and Web Application)

Tags: asp.net, iis, favicon

For a long time, IIS already supported Favicon file by just add a 16x16 images with the name `favicon.ico` in the root of the application.

However, I only see the favicon file support in the Website, but not in the Application.
[image]

From the image above, if i keep the favicon.ico in `Website`, it will applied even for the `Application` under the `Website`.

**Question:** How can I add a different favicon for Application that differently with the Website?

Comment: It is not an IIS feature, it is a browser feature. When the page does not define its favicon, the browsers look for it in the root of the domain, and not the root of the application. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447102/setting-favicon-in-html on how to define the favicon in the HTML.

Comment: @TasosK.Thank you, i found the solution in the post you send. Should i close my question or just post the answer i found out below?

Comment: I would say, that since the answer exists in another post, you should just close this one.

Comment: @TasosK. I voted to close it