# Html favicon not showing up

Tags: html, webpack, webpack-dev-server, favicon

My localhost web page hadn't show favicon, and also not found in **Network** request:

[image]
[image]

The **webpack-dev-server** host the web page including **index.html**, **favicon** and other files:

[image]

The **favicon.ico** can be accessed from `http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico` in browser.

Comment: Nothing here? https://www.google.nl/search?q=webpack+favicon.ico+localhost+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: change the format to **png** or other image format ex : `favicon.ico =>  favicon.png`

Comment: Maybe a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447102/why-does-my-favicon-not-show-up

Comment: I think cache problem. can you try `href="favicon.ico?v=1" `

Answer (score 2):

It's cache problem. I configured other port in webpack devServer and works.
Thanks @Hardik's

Answer (score 1):

check `webpack` setting for icon

```
 {
    test: /\.(ico)$/,
    use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]'
  }
```