# Favicon requested on every route change

Tags: react-router

[image: Favicon requested on every route change]

I think it's strange that a route change would trigger a request for the favicon.

Is this intended or what is going on here?

Comment: This is the exact problem I'm facing. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem!! Any solution??

Comment: I'm also experiencing this

Comment: It's 2022 and I still have this problem, even with the favicon `link` right at the top of the `head` element.  Crazy.  Chrome is *obsessed* with getting that favicon!

Comment: Here is solution: https://youtu.be/QMqcZjmghf4  ... the main issue is that  index.html   overwrites <helmet> favicon, BUT you can HACK it via priorities, e.g.   .ico  >   .png  and public folder > public/image folder and  32x32 > 72x72... so if you make   index.html  favicon  out of 72x72 .png  and put ALL your favicons into public/image  folder... the <helmet>  favicons should all be   32x32 .ico   then it works

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I believe the problem started with the Chrome 49.0.2623.87. I hope it is going to be fixed in the coming updates. For now, I am using the script below, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199902/isnt-it-silly-that-a-tiny-favicon-requires-yet-another-http-request-how-to-mak).

```
var favIcon = "favicon.ico";
var docHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];       
var newLink = document.createElement('link');
newLink.rel = 'shortcut icon';
newLink.href = 'data:image/png;base64,'+favIcon;
docHead.appendChild(newLink);
```

It will not stop the favicon requests, so for a short period of time you still will see the default favicon from chrome, but I believe there is not much to be done about that.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution [on Github](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally/issues/145#issuecomment-290356339). Quoting @Doeke:

> Try reordering the favicon link tags. For me, putting the 16x16 link before 32x32 fixed this issue. As for why this works... I have no idea.

For me, it meant putting the only favicon `<link>` on my page right at the top of `<head>`, after `<meta charset>`.

Comment: This worked! It seemed not having any favicon in the document was the real problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Change the `<link>` tag as mentioned below in `Step 6`, or follow the comments.

Embedding the `icon` inline as a `Data URL` will do the magic!

> ***What is a Data URL?***
> [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) allow content creators to embed small files inline in documents.

#### STEPS:

1. Convert favicon image to Data URI from this link: [Converter](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image/ico)
2. Upload the .ico file from the public folder.
3. Next, select output format as: `Data URI -- data:content/type;base64`
4. Next change the `<link>` tag's href with the generated output!
5. > Replace this line(`<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />`) in `public > index.html`.
6. > TO this line ↓↓

```html
<link
  rel="icon"
  href="data:image/x-icon;base64,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"
/>
```

***Now whenever this `href` is parsed, the DATA URL is loaded, instead of the .ico file. Hence, no new requests will be sent to the server as the data is embedded inline!***

Comment: This is by far the best solution - no need to include the image. If you need it in multiple places just create a CSS class and have it as background:              
`your-favicon {  
  background: url("data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAIA....") no-repeat;  
  width: 32px;  
  height: 32px;  
}`

Answer (score 2):

Try to serve `favicon.ico` from your server or add route for that. I was experienced such error when using express catch-all `app.get('*')` method which redirected all requests to `index.html` (even for favicon)

Answer (score 0):

Change the favicon request by the following line of code in your index.html page

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/vnd.microsoft.icon;base64,<data>">
```

here, `<data>` is the base64 data of your favicon.

refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

This trick stops the user’s browser from sending an automatic HTTP request for the favicon.

Answer (score 0):

For me, while using Next 13, replacing

`<head>` with `<Head>` (note case) seems to fix the issue.