# Is there a way to host a favicon on Google Drive for a Google Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have made several attempts to host an .ico file in Google Drive to use as a favicon for a Google Web App with no success. It just seems a little strange that there would be a `.setFaviconUrl()` method without a way to host .ico files.

So far I have tried:

1. To link to a publicly shared .ico file on Google Drive with `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=IMAGEURL`
2. Inserting an .ico file in a public Google Site and linking to the file's url

Both attempts give me the error:

> `The favicon icon image type is not supported.`

Comment: I just upload to imgur if there isn't a relevant domain to host it on. Google Drive is not supposed to be used as a content delivery network.

Comment: I just took a look at imgur. They do not seem to support .ico images

Comment: I use `.png`. You should clarify the source of the error.

Comment: Using `.png` does work.  Thank you for the suggestion.  However, I still would prefer to be able to stay within Google.

Comment: Wanting to use Google Drive as a CDN does not mean Google wants you to or has to let you. They have an entire business suite meant for that kind of thing - Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Does a PNG on Drive work?

Comment: No, I get the same errors as with a `.ico` file

Comment: inserting a .png file on a public google site should work though

Answer (score 4):

Took me a while to figure this out, if anyone needs this in the future.

You need to trick `.setFaviconUrl()` into thinking the image is a png without altering the link to the file. It seems like it checks the last 3 characters, so adding '&format=png' to the end of the download link was able to fix the issue for me.

Example: `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=IMAGEID&export=download&format=png`