# Why does Chrome request favicon on audio playback?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm loading and playing audio files using the `Audio()` constructor. This works fine in most browsers, but Chrome seems to make a new GET request for the site's favicon every time `.play()` is called. It looks like this happens regardless of file type, if it's a local file, same site or cross site.

It also seems to create a lot of garbage memory. Is there a way to prevent this?

Open DevTools and look at the networks tab while clicking the button in the example below.

```js
const bounce = new Audio('https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/bounce.mp3');

function playSound() {
    bounce.play();
}

document.getElementById('bounce').addEventListener('click', playSound, false);
```

```html
<button id="bounce">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appeared to be a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39402) in Chrome that is now marked as "fixed". However, as of September 19, 2020, [someone commented](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39402#c78) that is still occurring.

One possible workaround for this would be to include a "fake" icon in the `head` of your HTML. For example, the `link` element below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
    ... Rest of your HTML ...
```

This assigns an empty data URL to the favicon, and should prevent Chrome from automatically sending an HTTP request for it.

Comment: This solves the issue but there's also the question if I should make my game less nice with no favicon for everyone just because of a bug in one browser. Web development is not fun anymore.

Comment: You could try base64 encoding the favicon and using that in the `href` instead of the empty `data:,`, similar to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5199989

Comment: The base64 encoded favicon is the best compromise. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, trial and error I "developed" a working solution.

**When the problem happens?**
It *seems* that the `favicon.ico` request happens every time you play an audio, but actually not necessarily! It happens *ONLY* if the audio stopped and so it needs to start again. Not if it paused!

**Solution.**
So what you need is to pause the audio before it plays to the end and stops by itself.

```js
function play(audio) { // any normal instance of Audio element/tag
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    setTimeout(() => audio.pause(), audio.duration * 999)
}
```

```js
const bounce = new Audio('https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/bounce.mp3');

function playSound() {
    bounce.currentTime = 0;
    bounce.play();
    setTimeout(() => bounce.pause(), bounce.duration*999)
}

document.getElementById('bounce').addEventListener('click', playSound, false);
```

```html
<button id="bounce">Play</button>
```