# php script is executed multiple times per browser request

Tags: php, apache, debugging, virtualhost

I have a virtual host in apache. I am on ubuntu 10.04 using LAMP.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/username/websites/site_folder
ServerName www.site_folder.com
ServerAlias site_folder.com
    <Directory /home/username/websites/site_folder/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I added in /etc/hosts the line:

```
127.0.0.1 site_folder.com
```

Inside the folder of the vhost I added a php script named one.php, having the code:

```
<?php
$today = getdate();
$handle = fopen("logs/logs.txt", "a");
fwrite($handle, $today['mday'].'/'.$today['mon'].'/'.$today['year']." this is a log post"." \n");
fclose($handle);
?>
```

when I run the script from the browser, http://localhost/one.php or site_folder.com/one.php, the logs.txt has logged the same message 3 times:

```
12/4/2011 this is a log post 
12/4/2011 this is a log post 
12/4/2011 this is a log post
```

Using netbeans debugger I saw that that the script is actually repeated 3 times (after reaching the end of the script it continues from the start of the same script->one.php)
No .htaccess exists inside the folder.

What I have noticed is that the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] changes a bit each execution/repetition:

```
1)$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] => /one.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
2)$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] => /one.php
3)$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] => /one.php
```

I need to log my message only once.

I added the uncommented directives from apache2.conf :

```
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
LockFile /var/lock/apache2/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
DefaultType text/plain
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
LogLevel warn
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf
Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
Include /etc/apache2/ports.conf
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined
Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

Comment: Set up a single test.php file with no dependencies and try calling that. Make sure you have a file logger attached.

Comment: one.php has no dependencies, it contains only the code given, and logs a message each time executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reinstalled the server and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you tried it out, but..., have you tried to do it from a real server, instead a localhost one? I mean, the trouble maybe is in you Apache Server...

I don't know, just read it as a simple idea to test.

Comment: I am pretty sure this behavior is because of my local configuration (which I did not tweak at all except the virtual host in apache, I installed tasksel/LAMP), but I would like to know why

Comment: Can you post your httpd.conf file? Perhaps we can see the reason, thats your main config file in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had a simple visitors counter for all web pages of my website and logged info about returning visitors.

One of the pages was **.../reviews/1** *(where **/1** is a passed parameter to the reviews.php script)* and my reviews.php script was executed **even 5 times**, and after that 5 times, an **index.php** script was executed. So I finally got per every reviews page visit 5 more times increments in the counter of **reviews** page and 1 more time in the **index** page even though we open the reviews page. *(that was insane!!)*

I tried to echo `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to check what the requests were and 2 problems appeared:

1. I had `<img>` tags with some images (`<img src="assets/test.png">`)

   - I forgot to write the link as follows `<img src="**/**assets/test.png">`. (**Note that **/** slash before the assets)** , the server tried to access these images as it executed the request like this `http://demo_server/reviews/1/assets/test.png`. So it thought **assets/test.png** for additional request parameters to the **reviews.php script** and executed the script again.

     - I **removed the problem** as I corrected the links as I added that **/** in front of the link. `<img src="/assets/test.png">`
2. The second problem was the **executing of the index.php script** even if **I had no link or request** to this page in the **reviews.php

   - The problem was that the browser requests **/favicon.ico** by default and executes this URL: `http://demo_server/favicon.ico`. I tried this in **Chrome - there was a problem**, but in **Firefox - there wasn't**!
   - As my favicons were organized in another folder and named with different names for the different pixels and OS, the server tried by default to get the favicon.ico through **index.php page**. So the entire **index.php page was loaded in the background and this took time as well!**
   - I tried some answers from this StackOverflow post: [How to prevent favicon.ico requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests) but for no reason the most common answer `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:" />` didn't helped me and the **index.php** script was executed again.
   - Adding these lines of code into `.htaccess` **helped me** to block the request and not to load the whole **index.php** script and make slow performance of my **reviews page**:

     ```
     <IfModule mod_alias.c> 
             RedirectMatch 403 favicon.ico 
     </IfModule>
     ```

So finally, my saga was revealed and the counter was incrementing only **ONCE** as it should work.

I share this experience with the hope that it will help someone or will give him a direction in analyzing his or her problem of web development.

Sometimes our little mistakes make our bigger problems - as we say in our native country **"the stone overturned the cart"**.

**Cheers and Happy Coding!**