# WARNING Not Found: /favicon.ico in Django

Tags: python, django, warnings, favicon, ico

I'm new to Python and Django. I'm seeing this error message after I perform runserver, when trying to log in from my landing page,

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Running in development mode.
Running in development mode.
Running in development mode.
Running in development mode.
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4b1, using settings 'platformsite.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[21/Feb/2012 02:33:26] "GET /accounts/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10698
WARNING 2012-02-21 02:33:27,204 base 41333 4353703936 Not Found: /favicon.ico
[21/Feb/2012 02:33:30] "POST /accounts/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11098
WARNING 2012-02-21 02:33:30,581 base 41333 4362117120 Not Found: /favicon.ico
[21/Feb/2012 02:33:35] "POST /accounts/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10975
WARNING 2012-02-21 02:33:36,333 base 41333 4370530304 Not Found: /favicon.ico
[21/Feb/2012 02:33:57] "POST /accounts/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10975
WARNING 2012-02-21 02:33:57,670 base 41333 4349497344 Not Found: /favicon.ico
```

I'm on Python 2.7, Django 1.4, and  OS X 10.7
What is this warning about and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938028/how-can-i-get-a-favicon-to-show-up-in-my-django-app/57042608#57042608

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Most browsers look for the existence of an file called favicon.ico at the root path of your website domain, this controls the icon for the website you can see in your bookmarks folder or the address bar of your browser.

If you don't have one, then it's valid that it would return a Not Found error.

Comment: As Ignacio said; it's fine to ignore this; but if you're like to generate one then this site is helpful:  http://www.favicon.co.uk/

Comment: That site's a little out of date; favicons no longer need to be .ico files or very small images.

Comment: Fair enough! It's been a little while since I've needed one! Although, if you expect a certain amount of traffic to your new site then making it as small as possible is only doing a favour to your clients and customers, and a reduction in your own network traffic!  Every little bit helps.

Comment: It's pretty clear what the cause is, but if you don't want a favicon how would you disable the warning?

Comment: Hello, where is "root path of your website domain" exactly? I have put it next to the `config` folder, inside `templates` folder, inside `static` folder, but the Browser does not show the icon :(

Comment: @Shayan root path of your website domain is whatever comes right immediately after your domain name. So, for a domain `example.com`, you can say `logo.png` is in the root path of the domain if its URL is `example.com/logo.png`. 

This root path should not be confused with Django's project root or template directory.

Answer (score 40):

When you deploy to something like Apache, you will have to alias your favicon in a config file. However, while running Django in development mode, the following works

urls.py:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf.urls import url

url_patterns=[
    ...

    url(r'^favicon\.ico$',RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/images/favicon.ico')),
]
```

Comment: path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/favicon.ico')),

Comment: path("favicon.ico", RedirectView.as_view(url=static("favicon.ico"))). (django.templatetags.static)

Answer (score 13):

Almost all Browsers usually look for the existence of a file called `favicon.ico` at the root path of the website domain, this controls the icon for the website that we can see in the tabs, bookmarks folder or the address bar of the browser.

When the browser searches for `favicon.ico` and does not find the same, then it is valid that it would return a Not Found error.

`django.contrib.staticfiles.storage` provides `staticfiles_storage`, which is an instance of your project’s configured static file storage. Storages have a URL method that “[r]eturns an absolute URL where the file’s contents can be accessed directly by a Web browser.”, which is exactly what the `{% static %}` tag uses.

So `{% static 'favicon.ico' %}` in a template is essentially equivalent to `staticfiles_storage.url('favicon.ico')` in Python. We can add `<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'base/icons/favicon.ico' %}">` under `<head>` tag to the `base.html` of django.

When we get such error in other domains with error code 404, the link for favicon can be added under `<head>` section we can add `<link>` as follows:

```
<link rel="icon" href="static/projectname/favicon.ico">
```

or

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="base/icons/favicon.png"/>
```

Do not forget to add the required location of the icon file `favicon.ico`, the issue will be resolved.

The `favicon.ico` could be the logo of the company or anything the website is based upon.

Comment: Thanks, the approach with `<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'base/icons/favicon.ico' %}">` worked for me.  In my case I changed the subfolder path to just `img/favicon.ico` but it works for both the dev server (where files are served from the `static` top level folder) and on my production server (where they're served from a different folder populated via `python manage.py collectstatic`).

Answer (score 8):

- I was facing same problem `favicon.ico` not found.
- I converted my image file to `favicon.ico` from https://favicon.io/favicon-converter/.
- After downloading the zip file, then created new folder by name favicon and copy all the file inside zip or you can extract to favicon folder.
- After that I simply copied the favicon folder and pasted inside the static folder.
- I update this line of code in `urls.py` file, the folder in which our `settings.py` file exist.

  ```
   from django.urls import path
   from . import views
   from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
   from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

   urlpatterns = [    
        path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('favicon/favicon.ico')))
   ]
  ```
- Probably my error get solved.
- Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 6):

Your browser is looking for a favicon that it can display in the Location Bar. Either give it one, or ignore the warning.

Comment: A better answer would be to provide a code sample ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can serve static files by sending the `static_path` setting
    as a keyword argument. We will serve those files from the
    `/static/` URI (this is configurable with the
    `static_url_prefix` setting), and we will serve `/favicon.ico`
    and `/robots.txt` from the same directory.  A custom subclass of
    `StaticFileHandler` can be specified with the
    `static_handler_class` setting.
    """

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is to create an alias in your apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/your/favicon.ico
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was building a web api and ran into this as well.  As it was just a demo project, I threw a dummy response at the browser to make the error go away.  In the main `urls.py`, I added my little fake view above it.  Obviously, in production, you would just keep that icon in the static root, the location of which you set in the server config file.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def okay(request):
    return HttpResponse('pretend-binary-data-here', content_type='image/jpeg')

urlpatterns = [
    path('favicon.ico', okay),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the warning without setting your own **favicon**, add `<link rel="icon" ...>` to `<head></head>` in `base.html` as shown below. *[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests#38917888) explains `<link rel="icon" ...>` below and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938028/how-to-get-a-favicon-to-show-up-in-my-django-app/76924097#76924097) explains how to set **favicon** for Django and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959897/set-favicon-in-django-admin/76983640#76983640) explains how to set **favicon** for Django Admin:

```
{# "base.html" #}

<head>
...
<link rel="icon" href="data:,"> {# Here #}
...
</head>
```