# How to get a favicon to show up in my django app?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, favicon, django-staticfiles

I just want to drop the `favicon.ico` in my `staticfiles` directory and then have it show up in my app.

How can I accomplish this?

I have placed the `favicon.ico` file in my `staticfiles` directory, but it doesn't show up and I see this in my log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2014 10:10:53] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

If I go to `http://localhost:8000/static/favicon.ico`, I can see the favicon.

Comment: The error is `GET /favicon.ico` not `GET /static/favicon.ico` looking in `http://localhost:8000/static/favicon.ico` is not related. It looks like some browsers requests for  `/favicon.ico` despites the HTML.

Comment: @freezed, agree depends on browsers. and I don't like the solution with static, we must check favicon.ico framework/agreement for all browsers.

Comment: Here is a complete tutorial : https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-favicon-tutorial

Answer (score 235):

If you have a base or header template that's included everywhere why not include the favicon there with basic HTML?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  Can you point me to a link that explains how to do this?

Comment: Yeah. Something like: `{{STATIC_URL}}favicon.ico`

Comment: Edited answer with @karthikr's suggestion.

Comment: My favicon is not a .png file.

Comment: That's just an example. Modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me but other answers that used `href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}` did.

Comment: @user568021 You have other templates "extend" the base template. Your non-base templates then look like: `{% extends "app/base.html" %} {% block BLOCK_NAME %} ...actual content... {% endblock %}`

Comment: @NickChapman sorry for not being clear. that was not my question. By now I learned that you can 'include' other themplate files like this: {% include "appname/header.html" %} .. that was it.

Comment: Using {{STATIC_URL}} is not best practices, see for example http://staticfiles.productiondjango.com/blog/stop-using-static-url-in-templates/ . Use {% load static %} and <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}/> instead.

Comment: But if the favicon.ico won't show up if we request some static files.

Comment: MIME type (`image/png`) and file format (`favicon.ico`) doesn't match.

Comment: And don't forget to load static `{% load static %}` in the beginning of HTML template.

Answer (score 159):

One lightweight trick is to make a redirect in your `urls.py` file, e.g. add a view like so:

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

favicon_view = RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/favicon.ico', permanent=True)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^favicon\.ico$', favicon_view),
    ...
]
```

This works well as an easy trick for getting favicons working when you don't really have other static content to host.

Comment: I don't see how this is lightweight, compared to adding two lines to template. And this is kind of trick I wouldn't use in production.

Comment: @x-yuri  The other answer is easier, *if you have a base template at all*.  The point is you might not have any template or static content, so STATIC_URL may not even be configured.  e.g. it's a json API. but still want a browsable API without seeing 404 errors in your logs (chrome etc will try to request favicon.ico automatically). There is no harm to use such a RedirectView in production.

Comment: Should `url='/static/favicon.ico'` not be constructed dynamically, like as `url=settings.STATIC_URL + 'favicon.ico'` ? If I understand correctly, the proposed solution will only work as intended when in the settings.py file we have `STATIC_URL='/static/`.

Comment: @wim how would you apply this method to redirect a number of favicon formats so they are accessible in the root dir? e.g. you might have 10x apple touch sizes you want to deliver.

Comment: This is actually a good answer as some browsers look for /favicon.ico regardless of what is stated in the html file.

Answer (score 71):

In template file

```
{% load static %}
```

Then within `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{%  static 'favicon.ico' %}">
```

This assumes that you have static files configured appropiately in settings.py.

---

*Note*: older versions of Django use `load staticfiles`, not `load static`.

Answer (score 41):

In your `settings.py` add a root staticfiles directory:

```
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
        ]
```

Create `/static/images/favicon.ico`

Add the favicon to your template(base.html):

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

And create a url redirect in `urls.py` because browsers look for a favicon in `/favicon.ico`

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('images/favicon.ico')))
]
```

Comment: Hey. This seems to be the only way for me to display favicon - so thanks. But I still don't understand few things. 1: I don't seem to have to have the base.html change - favicon works without it. 2: urls.py change seems crucial, but I don't understand why I have to do this. Shouldn't the file be served by webserver ? That's why we need to do collectstatic, right ?

Comment: 1:because not all browsers can find the favicon if it's not declared in the html
2: as mentioned in the answer modern browsers look for favicon in that url

Answer (score 39):

## Universal solution

You can get the favicon showing up in Django the same way you can do in any other framework: just use pure HTML.

Add the following code to the header of your HTML template.
Better, to your base HTML template if the favicon is the same across your application.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'favicon/favicon.png' %}"/>
```

The previous code assumes:

1. You have a folder named 'favicon' in your static folder
2. The favicon file has the name 'favicon.png'
3. You have properly set the setting variable STATIC_URL

You can find useful information about **file format support** and how to use favicons in this article of Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon.
I can recommend use `.png` for universal browser compatibility.

**EDIT:**
As posted in one comment,
"Don't forget to add `{% load staticfiles %}` in top of your template file!"

Comment: Tipp: favicon.ico didnt do it for me, after testing with .png extension it worked!

Comment: You are right @kaya. The .ico format is not the best regarding compatibility. However .png always work.

Comment: saying file not found

Answer (score 12):

**First**

Upload your favicon.ico to your app static path， or the path you configured by STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py

**Second**

In app base template file:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

You can make apps use different favicon.ico files here.

**Addition**

In project/urls.py

```
from django.templatetags.static import static # Not from django.conf.urls.static 
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
```

Add this path to your urlpatterns base location

```
path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=static('favicon.ico'))),
```

This can let installed app(like admin, which you should not change the templates) and the app you forget modify the templates , also show a default favicon.ico

Answer (score 10):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'favicon/favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

Just add that in ur base file like first answer but ico extension and add it to the static folder

Answer (score 6):

if you have permission then

```
Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/aktel/workspace1/PyBot/PyBot/static/favicon.ico
```

add alias to your virtual host. (in apache config file ) similarly for robots.txt

```
Alias /robots.txt /var/www/---your path ---/PyBot/robots.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried the following settings in django 2.1.1

#### base.html

```
<head>
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}"/>
</head>
```

#### settings.py

```
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'` <br>`.............
```

#### Project directory structure

[image]

[view live here](http://codernote.azad.space)

Answer (score 6):

```
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon/sample.png' %}" />
```

Also run:  python manage.py collectstatic

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to override the Django base.html template. Make another base.html template under admin directory. Make an admin directory first if it does not exist. `app/admin/base.html.`

Add `{% block extrahead %}` to the overriding template.

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app/js/action.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'app/img/favicon.ico'  %}" />
{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}

    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Came across this while looking for help. I was trying to implement the favicon in my Django project and it was not showing -- wanted to add to the conversation.

While trying to implement the favicon in my Django project I renamed the 'favicon.ico' file to 'my_filename.ico' –– the image would not show. After renaming to 'favicon.ico' resolved the issue and graphic displayed. below is the code that resolved my issue:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}" />
```

Comment: I left my favicon directly inside static/. It turns out you need to have a folder between static/ and the icon. Now doing your method works!

Answer (score 1):

**Best practices :**

Contrary to what you may think, the favicon can be of any size and of any image type. [Follow this link for details.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

Not putting a link to your favicon can slow down the page load.

In a django project, suppose the path to your favicon is :

```
myapp/static/icons/favicon.png
```

in your django templates (preferably in the base template), add this line to head of the page :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{%  static 'icons/favicon.png' %}">
```

**Note :**

We suppose, the static settings are well configured in settings.py.

Answer (score 1):

Once configured the settings.py by adding

```
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
        ]
```

Copy your favicon on:
/yourappname/mainapp(ex:core)/static/mainapp(ex:core)/img

Then go to your mainapp template(ex:base.html)
and just copy this, after **{% load static %}** because you must load first the statics.

```
<link href="{% static 'core/img/favi_x.png' %}" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Now(in 2020),
You could add a base tag in html file.

```
<head>
<base href="https://www.example.com/static/"> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues regarding this one. But it has been resolved.
Make sure you have your directories correctly. For example, you have your images in this flow "templates-->users-->static-->images-->your-image.jpg".

** settings.py **

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/users/static')
]
```

** base.html **

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'images/your-image.jpg' %}" alt="Your Image">
```

I hope this helps  ~

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34232370)

Answer (score 0):

For me I needed to add another set of static variables in `settings.py`. I tried most answers above and moved my static folder into various locations, it always results in a 404.

#### settings.py

What was required and not mentioned above was:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Everything else as above in other answers:

#### template/html file

in the `head` section:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("favicon.ico", RedirectView.as_view(url='static/favicon.ico')),
    ...
```

edit: this SO page had the most relevant answers to my problem, however the favicon was still not showing. No other answer here addresses `STATICFILES_DIRS` directly. Several people mention about settings.py and the need to have the statics set up (eg `STATIC_URL` and others), however setting `STATICFILES_DIRS` was an immediate fix. It seems to be mentioned specifically only in the lower voted answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can show **favicon** on your browser with Django Development server. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959897/set-favicon-in-django-admin/76983640#76983640) explains how to set **favicon** in Django Admin.

For example, there is `favicon.ico` in `static/` and there is `base.html` in `templates/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-my_app1
 |-my_app2
 |-static
 |  └-favicon.ico # Here
 └-templates
    └-base.html # Here
```

Then, set `BASE_DIR / 'templates'` to [DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#dirs) in [TEMPLATES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#templates) and set `BASE_DIR / 'static/'` in [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) in `settings.py` as shown below so that Django can recognize `templates` and `static` folders just under `django-project`. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist#72359515) explains how to set Django Templates and I recommand to set [whitenoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise) following [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013735/turn-off-caching-of-static-files-in-django-development-server/76971577#76971577) to disable your browser to cache the static files of Django:

```py
# "settings.py"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates' # Here
        ],
        ...
    },
]

...

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static/' # Here
]
```

Lastly, add `<link rel="icon" ...>` to `<head></head>` in `base.html` as shown below:

```
{# "base.html" #}

<head>
...
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/> {# Here #}
...
</head>
```

In addition, if **favicon** is not shown on your browser, use different urls as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447473/favicon-issue-with-django-chrome/76979501#76979501) explains it:

```
http://localhost:8000/...
http://localhost:8001/...
http://localhost:8002/...
http://localhost: :: /...

http://127.0.0.1:8000/...
http://127.0.0.1:8001/...
http://127.0.0.1:8002/...
http://127.0.0.1: :: /...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from .views import *
from django.templatetags.static import static


urlpatterns = [
     ...
]

urlpatterns += [
    path("favicon.ico", RedirectView.as_view(url=static("favicon.ico"), permanent=True))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation that keeps `favicon.ico` at the website root path and does not touch the standard Django templates:

1. Place the `favicon.ico` file in a place accessible by `collectstatic`, so that it will be installed as `${STATIC_ROOT}/favicon.ico`:

   ```
   $ ls tax_refund/static/favicon.ico
   tax_refund/static/favicon.ico
   $ ./manage.py collectstatic
   (...)
   $ ls static/favicon.ico
   static/favicon.ico
   ```
2. For the built-in development server, add the `favicon.ico` route (it will be ignored by the production server):

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles import views

(...)
urlpatterns += [
    path('favicon.ico', lambda req: views.serve(req, 'favicon.ico'))
]
```

3. For the production server, directly serve it at the root path:

- uwsgi: `--static-map /favicon.ico=static/favicon.ico`
- nginx: `location /favicon.ico { alias static/favicon.ico; }`
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another point, according to MDN web docs, "The shortcut link type is often seen before icon, but this link type is non-conforming, ignored and web authors must not use it anymore." So, `rel="icon"` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

To actually put the favicon at the root of the server in development you do:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^(?P<path>favicon\.ico)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.BASE_DIR / 'path/to/favicon/'})
]
```

Notice I'm using `django.views.static.serve` not `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve`

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes restarting the server helps.

1. Stop the server and then rerun the command: `python manage.py runserver`
2. Now your CSS file should be loaded.