# Adding a favicon to template on Django

Tags: html, django, django-templates, favicon

I want to put a favicon in the base.html in my Django project, but it doesn't seems to work. It doesn't display any errors in the browser console, but I don't get the "GET" message in `python manage.py runserver`console.

```
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'assets/img/favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

Other static files such as JS and CSS are working just fine.

Here is my directory print: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMi6e.png)

And my python shell print: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W18Rd.png)

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938028/how-can-i-get-a-favicon-to-show-up-in-my-django-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the configuration in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

And in your templates, put this line on the to top:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```