# I try to add a picture of favicon.ico in Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

[How to add favicon.ico image in django project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeIMq.png)

Comment: You can reference this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284594/18553330

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to add favicon.ico file django project logo.