# How to server favicon.ico with Django and Whitenoise

Tags: django, whitenoise

I use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) for static files and it works fine.

But how can I serve the `/favicon.ico` file?

There is a setting called [WHITENOISE_ROOT](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html?highlight=favicon.ico#WHITENOISE_ROOT), but I don't understand how to use it.

I would like to keep my nginx config simple and serve all files via gunicorn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## If you want those files to be managed by `collectstatic`

Let's assume after running `collectstatic`, your `favicon.ico` file ends up being copied in a `root` subdirectory, located in your `STATIC_ROOT` directory.

Then, with:

```
WHITENOISE_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'root')
```

Whitenoise will serve all files in `STATIC_ROOT/root/` at the root of your application.

In your case, `STATIC_ROOT/root/favicon.ico` will be served at `/favicon.ico`.

## If you don't want those files to be managed by `collectstatic`

You can have a `root_staticfiles` folder in your `BASE_DIR` which simply contains the static files you want to serve at `/`.

```
WHITENOISE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'root_staticfiles')
```

In this case, Whitenoise will serve all files in `BASE_DIR/root_staticfiles/` at the root of your application.

## Update about `pathlib` (2022-10-04)

Since a while now, the default `settings.py` Django creates uses `pathlib`. To be consistent with it, one may replace `os.join` calls with `/` operators, eg.:

```py
WHITENOISE_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT / 'root'
```

Comment: My answer was unclear: you don't actually add any file in `STATIC_ROOT`, because this folder will be populatd by the `collectstatic` command.

Answer (score 3):

You could as per this [answer by hanleyhansen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21938098/14991864) add the following line in a base template (used by all further templates):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

Or you could write a redirect view like [this answer by wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21938270/14991864) with some little modification:

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.templatetags.static import static

re_path(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url=static('favicon.ico'), permanent=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a django app that uses Whitenoise (hosted on Heroku) and serves my favicon from a separate folder from my static files.

Make a folder `root_files` at path `BASE_DIR/root_files`.

In settings.py:

```
WHITENOISE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'root_files')
```

For a real-life code example checkout [Mozilla's Bedrock repo](https://github.com/mozilla/bedrock).  They have favicons in `BASE/root_files` and configure `WHITENOISE_ROOT` in [settings.py](https://github.com/mozilla/bedrock/blob/master/bedrock/settings/base.py)