# Favicon not appearing

Tags: html, django, django-staticfiles

For some reason my favicon is not appearing on chrome. I am using django. And I have a file named favicon.ico in my static folder.

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

Comment: Please show how you configured static files in settings.py, urls.py, clarify is Debug=true or false, what's the http response static when you try opening favicon url manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the image in static folder and make sure the image is an `ico` file

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'yourappname/images/favicon.png' type='image/ico' %}"/>
```

**OR**

You can store favicon as a png file too.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'yourappname/images/favicon.png' type='image/png' %}"/>
```

Additionally:

- Store your icon in **yourappname/static/yourappname/images/favicon.ico** path
- Make sure you have written <link rel... between the **`<head>`** tags in your template.
- Don't forget to use `{% load static %}` tag in your template.

You can find more details about 'using favicon' from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938028/how-can-i-get-a-favicon-to-show-up-in-my-django-app).

Comment: @Abrar Did you try with a png file too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230697/discussion-between-abrar-and-dil).

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'players/images/liverpool.png' type='image/png' %}"/>
```