# How to select the individual id of an HTML element that is within a for loop in a Django template?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, queryselector

I am trying to select an HTML button that is within a for loop in a Django template using a `querySelector` to add an event listener to it in JavaScript. How do you create a unique id for the button and select it through JavaScript? Right now, I have one id set to the button within the for loop, and when you press the button, nothing happens.

html

```
% for post in page_obj.object_list %}
            <div class = "individual_posts">
                <a href="{% url 'username' post.user %}"><h5 class = "post_user">{{ post.user }}</h5></a>
                <h6 id = "post_itself">{{ post.post }}</h6>
                {% if post.user == request.user %}
                    <button id="editButton" class="edit_button">Edit</button>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.querySelector('#editButton').onclick = edit_email();
})
```

Comment: Nothing is happening when you click because your `onclick` should be the function `edit_email` - as it is, you're calling it to early. But you're also repeating an ID multiple times in the document, which is invalid and won't work here. You should use a class instead, and use `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName` to loop through them all and add the `onclick` to each. (It's also better practice to use `addEventListener` than to assign to the `onclick` property.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) should definitely not be used, especially in conjunction with a loop.

Answer (score -1):

All of your buttons will have the same HTML id, one easy way of differentiating would be to include the forloop counter like so:

`id="editButton{{ forloop.counter0 }}"`

Then you can specify the button in your javascript.

However, I imagine you want to add the onclick functionality to all buttons. Your JS is selecting based on id using the `#` selector, if you change it to `('.edit_button')` it should work for all buttons

Comment: `id`s should generally be avoided in the first place as they create brittle code that doesn't scale well. Dynamic `id`s are an anti-pattern.

Comment: Hence the recommendation to use a class selector

Comment: @OsVoid, I changed the code to this: ```document.querySelector('.edit_button').addEventListener('click', () => edit_email());```. Nothing still happens, but I get this error ```GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)```. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Might be a problem with your `edit_email()` code - the 404 is a separate issue that your favicon url can't be found

Comment: favicon is the webpage icon you see at the top of your web browser, here's a useful answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938028/how-can-i-get-a-favicon-to-show-up-in-my-django-app

Comment: @OsVoid, I am no longer getting that error, but still nothing happens when you click the button.

Comment: If you replace `edit_email()` with `console.log("test")`, does 'test' appear in the console when you click the button?

Comment: @OsVoid, nothing happens in the console when I hit the button; 'test' doesn't appear either.

Comment: I've inserted your html button and JS code into my own browser and it works fine, do you still have 'edit_button' as your button class?

Comment: @0sVoid, I have ```document.querySelector('.edit_button').addEventListener('click', () => console.log("test"));```, but nothing happens in the console.

Comment: It should work, make sure your queryselector is `.edit_button` but the button class `edit_button` i.e. don't put the '.' in the actual class