# Set favicon in django admin

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, favicon, ico

I need to set up a favicon for django admin interface.

It would be best to do it globally, without overriding templates for all apps.

What is the cleanest way to do it? I tried searching Django documentation for this, but found nothing.

Answer (score 31):

To avoid duplicating anything of the original file, you can actually override the template while extending it ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template)). So create your own `template/admin/base_site.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'yourapp/img/favicon.ico' %}" />
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 26):

If favicon is in `/app/static/img/favicon.ico`, link it into the `{% block extrahead %}` of this file: `/app/templates/admin/base_site.html`

```
    {% extends "admin/base.html" %}

    {% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

    {% block extrahead %}
        <link rel="icon" href="{{STATIC_URL}}img/favicon.ico" sizes="48x48" />
    {% endblock %}
    {% block branding %}
        <h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}</a></h1>
    {% endblock %}
```

In `settings.py`, `INSTALLED_APPS` be sure your app is listed before `django.contrib.admin`.

To test get rid of template cache by deleting `.pyc` files:

```
$ find . -name \"*.pyc\" -delete".
```

Works with Django 1.8.12 Firefox, Chrome.

Answer (score 10):

Extend `admin/base.html` in your `template/admin/base_site.html` template and add the favicon link in *extrahead* block

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block extrahead %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'relative/path/to/favicon.ico' %}" />
{% endblock %}
```

**Django version >= 2**

Mind that the correct import, if using Django 2 or above, is:

```
{% load static %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Override the Django base.html template and put it under admin directory like `my_app/templates/admin/base.html.`

Add `{% block extrahead %}` to the overriding template.

```
   {% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% block javascripts %}
        {{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app/js/action.js' %}"></script>

    {% endblock %}

    {% block extrahead %}
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'app/img/favicon.ico'  %}" />
    {% endblock %}
    {% block stylesheets %}

        {{ block.super }}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: From Django 2.0 and above use {% load static %} instead of {% load staticfiles %}

Answer (score 3):

The best way who i find is put in urls:

```
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    urlpatterns = [
        path('favicon.ico', lambda _ : redirect('static/icons/favicon.ico', permanent=True)),
    ]
```

This way you have a favicon in all pages, that's include admins and django rest framework (i tested with both) and favicon set with *link* tag in tamplate staying working.

Answer (score 1):

You can set **favicon** for Django Admin. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938028/how-to-get-a-favicon-to-show-up-in-my-django-app/76924097#76924097) explains how to set **favicon** for Django.

For example, put `favicon.ico` in `static/` and copy [base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html` in your virtual environment to `templates/admin/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-my_app1
 |-my_app2
 |-static
 |  └-favicon.ico # Here
 └-templates
    └-admin
       └-base.html # Here
```

Then, set `BASE_DIR / 'templates'` to [DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#dirs) in [TEMPLATES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#templates) and set `BASE_DIR / 'static/'` in [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) as shown below so that Django can recognize `templates` and `static` folders just under `django-project`. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist#72359515) explains how to set Django Templates and I recommand to set [whitenoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise) following [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013735/turn-off-caching-of-static-files-in-django-development-server/76971577#76971577) to disable your browser to cache the static files of Django:

```py
# "settings.py"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates' # Here
        ],
        ...
    },
]

...

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static/' # Here
]
```

Lastly, add `<link rel="icon" ...>` in `base.html` as shown below:

```
{# "base.html" #}

<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
{# ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ #}
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
{# ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ #}
{% block dark-mode-vars %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "admin/css/dark_mode.css" %}">
  <script src="{% static "admin/js/theme.js" %}" defer></script>
{% endblock %}
```

In addition, if **favicon** is not shown on your browser, use different urls as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447473/favicon-issue-with-django-chrome/76979501#76979501) explains it:

```
http://localhost:8000/...
http://localhost:8001/...
http://localhost:8002/...
http://localhost: :: /...

http://127.0.0.1:8000/...
http://127.0.0.1:8001/...
http://127.0.0.1:8002/...
http://127.0.0.1: :: /...
```