# Favicon issue with Django - Chrome

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, browser, favicon

I'm having a pretty absurd issue everywhere. Every new Django project I create is utilizing an old favicon that I made a long time ago. In other words, all new Django projects have this old favicon and I have no idea how or why it's accessing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: It might just be cached? Have you forced a refresh (Ctr/Cmd+ R)?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't do the trick. I also attempted Ctrl + F5 method but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points to consider:

**How you access your sites under development**

If you use a generic URL such as `http://localhost`, your browser considers all your sites to be the same one. Thus, you suffer from cross-site caching issues. If so, you can try the well-known solutions described in [How to force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh). An alternative solution is to use you hosts file (`/etc/hosts` on Linux or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows). Add lines such as:

```
127.0.0.1 myfirstsite.com
127.0.0.1 mysecondsite.com
```

Then, browse your sites under development just like a regular site with `http://myfirstsite.com` or `http://mysecondsite.com`.

**Duplicated favicon(s)**

Is there any chance your icons are duplicated?

- Maybe you have duplicated declarations in your HTML. Some browsers may use the first one, some others the second one.
- Maybe you have a duplicated favicon in your root directory (ie. `http://example.com/favicon.ico`). This is a convention, so some browsers may pick this one instead of the one you declared in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give them a shot. I deleted the Favicon folder in Chrome but that didn't seem to solve the issue. 

I did notice something weird though. When I go to Django's default server URL (http://127.0.0.1:8000/), I see the favicon. However, when I just go to localhost:8000, I DON'T see the favicon. Hopefully this will help me pinpoint the issue!

Answer (score 0):

If **favicon** is still not shown on your browser by clearing browser's cache, then you should use different urls.

For example, you use the url below:

```
http://localhost:8000/...

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then, change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` as shown below:

```
       ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
http://127.0.0.1:8000/...

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Or, change the port as shown below:

```
                 ↓↓↓↓
http://localhost:8001/...
                                   ↓↓↓↓
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```