# How to add a logo to the site index bar using django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-staticfiles

Can anyone help me on how to add a logo to the index bar in Django-admin site?
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question is answered here.
You have to override Django base.html template and put it under the admin directory.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44428576/7122788

Answer (score 1):

You should probably override (by extend) the `app_index.html` admin template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model

So you need to create a `template/admin` directory in your application and override the correct template by adding you own logo.

[Edit]

Oh sorry, you screenshot was too small and I just realized that you’re talking about the icon in the tabbar. That would be the *favicon*. For that, it’s simple, just add a `favicon.ico` into your `static/` folder, and serve that directly from your http server (probably with a alias).

You can also serve the file directly using a simple view, but that doesn’t seems like a good idea except in development.

Comment: Sorry for the small image

Comment: can you guide me on how to add a `favicon.ico`

Comment: I think we should override base_site.html for logo addition

Answer (score 0):

Override the Django base.html template and put it under the admin directory like `my_app/templates/admin/base.html`

Add `{% block extrahead %}` to the overriding template.

```
   {% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app/js/action.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico'  %}" />
{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}

    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```