# Django doesn't override base admin template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add small customizations to my Django admin panel such as a favicon.

I followed the [official guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template) and have created a `base_site.html`file in `app/templates/admin/`.

base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block branding %}
    <img src="{% static 'portal/img/favicon.png' %}" alt="Favicon">
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

It seems like the template isn't being overridden at all as I don't see an error for not being able to find the favicon  / incorrect src (works fine on other pages).

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


sitemaps = {
    'static': StaticViewSitemap,

}
 
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name="admin"),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your base_site.html file correctly extends the base template:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'portal/img/favicon.png' %}" />
{% endblock branding %}
```

If not helpful, please see : [Set favicon in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959897/set-favicon-in-django-admin)

Comment: The django site says to extend `base_site.html` not, `base.html`. I'll give it a try however

Answer (score 0):

To override an admin template, the app holding the templates (`app`, apparently) needs to be listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` ahead of `django.contrib.admin`. Is that the case here?

Comment: This is the root app, it is installed.