# Source maps security

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, source-maps

[Source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) are extremely helpful when stepping through minified library code, among other things. The first few lines of a .js file using source maps could look like this by default:

```
/*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map
*/
```

If you don't have `jquery.min.map` in the same directory, a browser that supports source mapping will make a redundant http request resulting in a 404 error ([sounds familiar, favicon anyone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1321878/1081234)).

I've noticed that `sourceMappingURL` could point to another domain; I'm not advocating the practice but it seems peculiar that it wouldn't be subject to CORS:

```
/*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.map
*/
```

Are mapped unminified sources safe? i.e. if in the example above the mapped server were compromised and malicious code added to the source, could/would it get executed? What about if you're debugging code and stepping through it? I can't find any implementation details that would answer this.

Comment: The code in the source map isn't executed, it's just used for display in the debugger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use JavaScript source maps (.map files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/how-to-use-javascript-source-maps-map-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you step through code, you're executing the minified code, not the code in the source map. The source map is just used for display in the debugger.