# How can I use JavaScript source maps (.map files)?

Tags: javascript, source-maps

Recently I have seen files with the `.js.map` extension shipped with some JavaScript libraries (like [Angular](http://code.angularjs.org/)), and that just raised a few questions in my head:

- What is it for? Why do the guys at Angular care to deliver a `.js.map` file?
- How can I (as a JavaScript developer) use the `angular.min.js.map` file?
- Should I care about creating `.js.map` files for my JavaScript applications?
- How does it get created? I took a look at `angular.min.js.map` and it was filled with strange-formatted strings, so I assume it's not created manually.

Comment: The accepted answer links to a video at mozilla.org explaining what a sourcemap is, but I found [this intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGed9phNkto) to be better. Not saying it's perfect, but it goes through a few webpack sourcemap settings showing how each changes the appearance of a simplest-case chunk of code in dev tools as you debug. Spoiler: There's a range of [minimized to original] code. The closer you are to minimized, the faster the sourcemap is created but the uglier the code might be. Closer to original & you get more human-readable code but pay in sourcemap transpilation time

Answer (score 820, accepted):

The `.map` files are for JavaScript and CSS (and now TypeScript too) files that have been minified. They are called [source maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map). When you minify a file, like the *angular.js* file, it takes thousands of lines of pretty code and turns it into only a few lines of ugly code. Hopefully, when you are shipping your code to production, you are using the minified code instead of the full, unminified version. When your app is in production, and has an error, the source map will help take your ugly file, and will allow you to see the original version of the code. If you didn't have the source map, then any error would seem cryptic at best.

Same for CSS files. Once you take a [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) or [Less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29) file and compile it to CSS, it looks nothing like its original form. If you enable sourcemaps, then you can see the original state of the file, instead of the modified state.

So, to answer you questions in order:

- **What is it for?** To de-reference uglified code
- **How can a developer use it?** You use it for debugging a production app. In development mode you can use the full version of Angular. In production, you would use the minified version.
- **Should I care about creating a js.map file?** If you care about being able to debug production code easier, then yes, you should do it.
- **How does it get created?** It is created at build time. There are build tools that can build your .map file for you as it does other files. *[Sourcemaps fail if the output file is not located in the project root directory #71](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/issues/71)*

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: note that the map file will not be sent untill you call it, that is what made me confused http://stackoverflow.com/a/27196201/861487

Comment: @frosty **To de-reference uglified code**. Can you explain this please? Doesn't a `.js.map` file maintains a relation (oftentimes called *reference*) between hand-crafted file and a minified file?

Comment: @student it says de-reference because I don't want to reference the minified code. It is minified and if I look at it, it is next to worthless. But, if it could de-reference it back to the original source, that would be epic. And that is exactly what a sourcemap is. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 67):

#### How can a developer use it?

1. **Don't link** your *js.map* file in your *index.html* file (no need for that)
2. Minification tools (good ones) add a comment to your *.min.js* file:

   ```
   //# sourceMappingURL=yourFileName.min.js.map
   ```

   which will connect your **.map** file.

   When the *min.js* and *js.map* files are ready...
3. Chrome: Open *dev-tools*, navigate to *Sources* tab. You will see the *sources* folder, where un-minified applications files are kept.

Comment: How can I provide a source map from my local filesystem if this comment is not present in the minified source and I cannot modify it?

Answer (score 50):

I just wanted to focus on the last part of the question; **How are source map files created?** by listing the build tools I know that can create source maps.

1. [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com): using plugin [`grunt-contrib-uglify`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-uglify/)
2. [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/): using plugin [`gulp-uglify`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-uglify/)
3. [Google closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/): using parameter [`--create_source_map`](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/faq#sourcemaps)

Comment: 2021 Update: If using ES6 JS, try using `gulp-terser`.  `gulp-uglify` as I understand, does not support ES6.  If you are using Babel to transpile to ES5, then no issues.

Comment: There is a tool written in Ruby that I've used before: https://github.com/ConradIrwin/ruby-source_map. I'm looking for something written in python or c.

Answer (score 18):

The map file maps the unminified file to the minified file. If you make changes in the unminified file, the changes will be automatically reflected to the minified version of the file.

Comment: Re *"the changes will be automatically reflected"*: Presuming the [minification tool does it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/how-can-i-use-javascript-source-maps-map-files/36554691#36554691)? What are some examples of such minification tools?

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to how to use map files: I use Google Chrome for Ubuntu and if I go to sources and click on a file, if there is a map file a message comes up telling me that I can view the original file and how to do it.

For the Angular files that I worked with today I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and a list of original files comes up in a small window.

I can then browse through the list to view the file that I would like to inspect and check where the issue might be.