# Different CSS setup in pure html+css+js than in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have downloaded store template written in HTML+CSS+JS, than i have made some corrections and it was working just fine.
When i wanted to connect it to my express website it was working but not as it should. I'm using hbs, posted all images, scripts and plugins to public folder but sill i have some issue:

1. I see that there is not the same css code (i have delated older css files). I have a way more classes on node server.
2. I have a few errors:

`GET /styles/bootstrap4/popper.js.map 404 32ms - 9.4kb
GET /styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js.map 404 37ms - 9.4kb
GET /styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css.map 404 10ms - 9.4kb`

Comment: We'll need your code.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196117/why-using-jquery-map) as well

Comment: @JackBashford I am looking for someone who had simila problem. I'm not able to send you all my code, because i have no idea where is a problem: 
-in css
-in express
-in some plugins
i have no idea, i cant afford sending my entire project, so i'm looking for an idea

Answer (score 0):

`.map` is the source map file of JS libraries like Bootstrap or jQuery; it's **only** for development use. Since you're using the minified version of JS and CSS, without the source map, the errors will look cryptic (as the minified version is probably not human-readable).

In short, you can upload the `.map` files along with your CSS and JS to suppress the errors (well, that's safe to ignore though). Without the source map files, your site will still be working.

Comment: Thanks, so than i have a prolem why there is 2 different css in node and without node