# Why don't javascript source maps show up in the network logs of a browsers developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, source-maps

When I load my web app and view the network tab in developer tools I see the logs of the loaded resources such as the .html .js .png requests.  However I don't see any network requests for .js.map why is this?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific than this.  What is a `.js.map` file and why would I be downloading it into my browser as a user of your application?

Comment: javascript source maps contain a .js.map extension.  You would be including it along with the minified javascript in order to debug the minified javascript code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27196201.  *"Source maps are loaded only when the developer tools are active. Browsers won't load them for application's users."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey The network tab that I use to view the logs is part of the developer tools. I updated my question to be more specific