# Pretty-Print not retained during Chrome browser Javascript debugging

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging, pretty-print

While debugging Javascript code in Chrome Browser, I enabled `pretty-print` by pressing the `{ }` button at the bottom left corner of the `Source`window.

However after enabling breakpoint and stepping through the code, the print goes back to normal. I pressed the pretty-print button again and after the next step-through, it goes back to normal. This continues and hinders my debugging.

Any way to retain pretty-print while debugging ?

Comment: Similar question (possible duplicate) here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105261/how-to-force-chrome-debugging-tools-to-debug-in-pretty-code