# Debugging Minified JavaScript Using Chrome on Production Environment

Tags: javascript

We have an issue on the production environment. The production script is minified. So, when we debug using Chrome we cannot get hold of the actual variables. But we can see the values in the minified variables. Is there any plugin or some option that will still give us a non-minified view on any environment so it will be easier to fix instead of guessing about the values in minified variables.

Comment: Take a look at [Source Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/javascript-map-files-javascript-source-maps).

Answer (score 2):

The typical solution for this problem is to use [source maps](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps).