# Chrome loading the .SCSS files, but it actually doesn't exist in respective directory

Tags: javascript, sass, less, web-development-server

few days back I have cloned a website from htrack tool. When I looked into chrome sources tab of developer tools. I can see there is some files are loading .SCSS files. And the coding of inside .scss files actually working. But when I tried to find/map the same file it's no where in the same directory. I also done show hidden files but not showing same files still. I really wonder how can this possible that a browser can load the file that actually not exist..??

I am using windows 10.

[image]  [image][image][image]

Comment: It's probably because of _sourcemap_ files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21719713/1534704