# ng test --watch=false ERR code ELIFECYCLE when test fail

Tags: testing, npm, jasmine, angular8

i have a problem, i don't think it's normal.

When i launch the command 'ng test --watch=false' with at least one test in error (wrong expect) the command quit with this error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ulys-nav@0.0.1 test: `ng test --watch=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ulys-nav@0.0.1 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/martels3/.npm/_logs/2019-10-21T11_20_00_883Z-debug.log
```

But when i fix the test (correct expect), every is normal (without error).

Here is my karma.conf.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
process.env.CHROME_BIN = puppeteer.executablePath();

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']
      }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    captureTimeout: 210000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 210000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 210000
  });
};
```

Is it normal to have this horrible error?
Because when i launch this command in the CI (bitRise), it quit because of this and i don't want to !

Comment: I found why there is this error, it's because i call the command with 'npm run test' and not 'npm test'. With 'npm test', i have this error "npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details". How can i avoid the npm ERR when i have one test which failed ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you still have the problem. I think I have the solution for you even if it's not the best one. The reason for this kind of problems is the configuration of the `sourceMap`property. If you search for the keyword in your project you will find it in `angular.json` and `tsconfig.json`

In `angular.json` is is set to false and in `tsconfig.json` it is true. While set to true the browser disconnects and the tests do not work. So the solution is to configure you command like this:

```
ng test --source-map=false --watch=false
```

For me this is the solution that helps because the sourceMap seems to be buggy. Related to this GitHub issue https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3267 and an explaination what `sourceMaps` are:

[What will happen if sourcemap is set as false in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879588/what-will-happen-if-sourcemap-is-set-as-false-in-angular)