# Angular12 console logs only from main.js:1 and polyfills.js:1

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm building a new angular app and anywhere I do console.log's it comes from main.js:1 or polyfills.js:1 and not from the proper component.

```
"localdev": {
"fileReplacements": [
{
"replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
"with": "src/environments/environment-localdev.ts"
}
]

"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~12.1.0-",
"@angular/cdk": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/common": "~12.1.0-",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.1.0-",
"@angular/core": "~12.1.0-",
"@angular/forms": "~12.1.0-",
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it comes from those files? Are you logging a trace that points to those files?

Comment: Perhaps your build is not generating source maps? See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879588/what-will-happen-if-sourcemap-is-set-as-false-in-angular

Comment: wrote a comment in home.component.ts, should show the same right, but it showing as main.ts.1 .. I mentioned angular version details and angulaer.json localdev config code @DKidwell

Comment: sourcemap set to false in angular.json @TotallyNewb

Comment: Read what source maps do. Without sourcempas you can't debug, as all you get is minified and bundled code. Enable sourcemaps for your development environment and while debugging you will be able to access the unminifed, unbundled code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Type column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.type }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.name }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Header row for 'type' and 'name' -->
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['type', 'name']"></tr>

  <!-- Family grouping with 'name' and two columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="familyGroup">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="2">
      <div (click)="element.expanded = !element.expanded">
        {{ element.family }}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="element.expanded">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let groupItem of element.items">
          <tr>
            <td mat-cell [attr.colspan]="2">
              <div (click)="groupItem.expanded = !groupItem.expanded">
                {{ groupItem.name }}
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="groupItem.expanded">
                <table>
                  <tr *ngFor="let item of groupItem.items">
                    <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Family group row -->
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['familyGroup']; let i = index"
    [class.expanded]="row.expanded" [class.collapsed]="!row.expanded"
  ></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is it supposed to mean?