# Angular app builds white screen after upgrading to version 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

### Issue description

I recently upgraded Angular app from `v11` to `v12`. The whole upgrading process finished successfully without errors. However, when I build my application, application bootstraps as "white screen", and there are NO errors in the console.

The result is empty `<router-outlet>` tag:

[image]

### During debugging I noticed a few things

1. All code from `app.component.ts` got executed
2. Code from `main.ts` got executed up until the point where app should be bootstrapped:

```js
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch((error) => {
```

3. App only builds "white screen" with `ng serve` (development build), but builds fine on `ng build` (production build)

### Reason of the issue

After 2 days of debugging I noticed that when I remove `"sourceMap": true` config from `angular.json` file, application builds fine with `ng serve` (development build) as well.

### Question

Does anyone know why application builds "white screen" with `"sourceMap": true` config and how to prevent it? I would like to keep that config because of debugging purposes.

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879588/what-will-happen-if-sourcemap-is-set-as-false-in-angular) link. It is useful for debugging purpose, not sure what it has to do with the app rendering. There might be some config issue which should be changed. IVY rendering is enabled/disabled?

Comment: It would be useful if you could share the whole angular.json since it looks like some problem with the project's configuration.

Comment: I checked that already and as I understand it should not change anything except it would also generate source map. I don't know why app is building "white screen" only with that option set to true. I started happening after upgrade to v12. Ivy is enabled. @ApoorvaChikara