# A react build folder when run using the serve package exposes the src files in the inspector

Tags: reactjs

I ran the react build script and it has built the files into a build folder. However when I use serve (or any static file serve package), I am able to see the files from the src folder when I check the inspector. The react components files can be seen from the inspector.

[The actual directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kptjg.png)

[The files in the chrome inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jSX3.png)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: This is not an issue. This is how source maps work.

Comment: How can I go about hiding these files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21719713/1695393 has more details on sourcemaps... if you want to hide them, delete any `.map` files from your build directory

Comment: There are no these files. They are shown only in dev tools. If you believe you don't need source maps, remove .map files in production build, but you will have hard time debugging your app.