# Uncaught ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined(ckeditor5)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I am trying to setup the ckeditor5 in my local but I am facing this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>   sample.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined

Below is the local code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CKEditor 5 – Classic editor</title>
<script src="ckeditor1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Classic editor</h1>
<textarea name="content" id="editor">
    &lt;p&gt;This is some sample content.&lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the same is working when I am pointing to cdn ckeditor url:

```
https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/12.3.0/classic/ckeditor.js
```

[working cdn jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pu7v289o/1/)

Answer (score 7):

It's not working because you don't have editor script loaded, so there's no `ClassicEditor`.

You need to load the editor from cdn first: `<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/12.3.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>`

Comment: I have added a local file in script  and that file got downloaded in network tab.

Comment: no when having script in local it is not working but when pointing to cdn it is working.

Comment: Well, do you have the script in the root of your app?

Comment: This still does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is worked for me

```
window.addEventListener("load", (e)=>{
    ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but when I looked in the files I found a folder called
sample and in that folder there was an 'index.html' file and when I opened it on my browser that was an sample if the editor.

And you can look at the script section or just copy that.

also in the body tag according to that index.html you shoul add `data-editor="ClassicEditor"`

Hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a map file in the build that has to be included in the root.  ckeditor.js.map   this had worked for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: The .map file is used for debugging purposes; whether or not it's included in root should not affect CKEditor's ability to function.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/how-can-i-use-javascript-source-maps-map-files