# angular cli duplicate chunk name after ng build

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8, angular-cli-v8

I'm developing Angular v8 app with using Angular CLI v8.

I have `dashboard.module.ts`

And after executing command `ng-build` I see in `dist` folder files with names:

```
dashboard-dashboard-module.js
```

Why not `dashboard-module.js`?

Why it's duplicate `dashboard-dashboard`?

What's the reason of naming it such way? Or it's default behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript .map files - javascript source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/javascript-map-files-javascript-source-maps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of your chunk is built following this pattern: 
`{ModuleDirectoryName}-{ModuleName}.js`

So if your module path looks like **dashboard/dashboard.module.ts**, the built chunk will be named **dashboard-dashboard-module.js**

If you want to change the naming pattern, one possibility is to use the webpack Plugin [angular-named-lazy-chunks-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-named-lazy-chunks-webpack-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue, a work around is modify your `dashboard.module.ts` into `module.ts`