# How to protect React.js source code with production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-redux, frontend

I have created a React.js app after the final production build.
I have found Source code on the browser network tab on fetch:

[image: issue]

After clicking on `agent_list.js` it shows source js code

How to secure this one ?

Comment: How would the browser read the source code if it can't read the source code?

Comment: bundle it in a single minified file....

Comment: Do not include source maps in production deployments and only deploy the minified bundles.

Comment: @MattEllen
Component source code display after click browser source tab display agent_list.js file 

http://prntscr.com/qktt3t

Comment: Yes bundle in minified  but agent_list.js component source code after click display @Jai

Comment: i have ```npm run build``` command for production can you give me command for it @crashmstr

Comment: What you put on the server is important. Do *not* put `.map` files from your build folder on the server, as those contain a way to map the minified chunks to the "human readable" source.

Comment: A final note: if you are running this locally, then being able to see the code *is expected* to allow you to debug in the browser with your original source. When you *deploy*, you do not deploy or do not allow the user to access the `.map` files so that this level of code is not visible. See: [Javascript .map files - javascript source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21719562/1441)

Comment: I have deleted .map file but after delete it is not working error below link @crashmstr

http://prntscr.com/qkuqu0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205608/discussion-between-rajesh-smartwebtech-and-crashmstr).

Comment: i have got it 
added GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true in env file 
it is working 
Thank you @all

Comment: Hi guys, may I ask is using server side rendering framework such as NextJS helps in prevent source code exposed to client side? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless you did not use `create-React-app` (CRA), your code should be `uglyfied` and `minified`, because CRA comes with `webpack` by default, which handles your app `bundling` (even in dev mode). Otherwise I’d recommend you to research the terms between `quotes` to familiarize your self more with the topic.