# How can I fix the "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content" error when adding a JavaScript library?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, tensorflow.js, source-maps

#### My code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
    <!-- Load Posenet -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet"></script>
 </head>

  <body>
    <img id='cat' src='./pose/images/aa_085.jpg'/>
  </body>
  <!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
  <script>
    var flipHorizontal = false;

    var imageElement = document.getElementById('cat');

    posenet.load().then(function(net) {
      const pose = net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
        flipHorizontal: true
      });
      return pose;
    }).then(function(pose){
      console.log(pose);
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

I rarely use HTML and JavaScript and almost forget the most fundamentals. What is the error?

#### Error information

> [DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tf.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: The URL is incorrect, the resource was not found.

Comment: but this is given by Tensorflow doc

Comment: Just put that URL to the address bar and hit ENTER, the resource doesn't exist.

Comment: no, it works. Just tried.

Comment: What sourcery is that? If I click the link, the page says "_Failed to resolve the requested file._".

Comment: No, I put the src links which are in the script tag on the addr bar

Comment: The script loading wasn't the problem, "_Could not load content for ..._" is ..?

Comment: can you tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Newer files on JsDelivr get the sourcemap added automatically to the end of them. This is fine and doesn't throw any SourceMap-related notice in the console as long as you load the files from JsDelivr.

The problem occurs only when you copy and then load these files from your own server. In order to fix this for locally loaded files, simply remove the last line in the JavaScript file(s) downloaded from JsDelivr.

It should look something like this:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=/sm/64bec5fd901c75766b1ade899155ce5e1c28413a4707f0120043b96f4a3d8f80.map
```

As you can see, it's commented out, but Chrome still parses it.

Comment: Removing that line fixed showing that warning, but I have no idea what it does.

Comment: This should be the top answer +1

Comment: This works, but could anyone please explain why it was there and what it does?

Comment: Source map urls, by definition, are comments (see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map)). So the only solution is to remove it.

Comment: What if you add a space between "//" and "#"? Is there a difference? (Google's (internal) coding standards mandates a space.)

Comment: That line has apparently been [inserted by a minification tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/how-can-i-use-javascript-source-maps-map-files/36554691#36554691).

Comment: Nope. This doesnt solve the problem. My Json is formatted correctly. Only Chrome Developer console showing this error, but the script is still working regardless. just ignore?

Comment: @PeterMortensen google seems to mandate no space in this case (https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sourcemaps/); adding the space fixes it for me, but I think because its the equivalent of such a statement not being there; i.e. no space is the required syntax

Answer (score 138):

This worked for me:

Go to Inspect → Settings (Symbol) gear → Uncheck *Enable JavaScript source maps* and *Enable CSS source map*.

Refresh.

(Note: Deactivate [Adblock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus) if the above process did not work.)

Comment: It worked, but isn't this removing the question and not fixing it? the problem is solved on browser terminal not in web page code!

Comment: This answer is basically "if it doesn't work, just uninstall and the error will be gone"

Comment: Great answer - however, if I don't want (and don't need) source maps then why would Chrome Devtools be bugging me about it? The unselected state of those 2 checkboxes should be the default ...

Comment: Deactivating AdBlock not solving the problem

Comment: @Usama Try next steps.

Comment: Unchecking those 2 options **without** disabling the AdBlock solved the problem.

Comment: How did this get 76 upvotes? This is wrong. Are you going to disable this on each users PC that uses your webpage?

Comment: This only remove warning message from your browser and this is like skipping a problem.

Comment: Another solution is to close your eyes. I now keep my eyes closed at all times, and I never see this warning. Problem solved!

Comment: Note that by following this answer, u won't be able to see TypeScript files in dev tools `Console` and `Sources` tab.

Answer (score 23):

This is what worked for me:

Instead of

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
```

try

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"> </script>
```

After that change I am not seeing the error any more.

Comment: This link stopped it from working all-together for me. The original link ("instead of" listed above) works still, but throws the same error in the question (as of 12/2022).

Answer (score 16):

Also I'd faced the same kind of problem for Telerik's [Kendo UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telerik#Controls_Suite) JavaScript file. For that you need to uncheck options 'Enable JavaScript source maps' and 'Enable CSS source map' from the Inspect element as shown in image and *refresh* the web page.

[image: In setting of the Inspect element]

[image: Uncheck the options 'Enable JavaScript source maps' and 'Enable CSS source map']

Comment: This removes the message, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It does solve the problem, assuming that I'm not interested in source maps

Comment: No, this is completely wrong. This is only for your browser, are you expecting each user that uses this webpage to change their settings?

Comment: This is essentially identical to [GAURAV MOKASHI's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205390/when-adding-a-javascript-library-chrome-complains-about-a-missing-source-map-w/63383126#63383126)  (though with an awesome screenshot).

Answer (score 14):

When it’s annoying with warnings like

`DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://********/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`

follow this path and **remove** that tricky
`/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */` line in file *bootstrap.min.css*.

Comment: This is similar to [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205390/when-adding-a-javascript-library-chrome-complains-about-a-missing-source-map-w/64152797#64152797).

Comment: That line has apparently been [inserted by a minification tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/how-can-i-use-javascript-source-maps-map-files/36554691#36554691).

Comment: @CodeToLife this works. Any idea how it worked ?
or the reason of existence of `/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */` line ?

Comment: @sashiksu, oh, it was too long since. Just "plug and play". Currently busy with other things

Comment: you are a king!

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had to deactivate [Adblock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus) and it worked fine.

Comment: but that won't be done to all computers.

Comment: Thank you. This approach worked for me. Frankly this error is really annoying.

Answer (score 7):

I used the minified version of the CSS file and it worked for me.

Use:
`import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css'`

Instead of: `import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'`

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to remove React Dev Tools from Chrome to stop seeing the strange errors during development of React application using a local Express.js server with a [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) client (which uses [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack)).

In the interest of community, I did a sanity check and quit everything - server/client server/Chrome - and then I opened Chrome and reinstalled React Dev Tools... I started things back up and am seeing this funky address and error again:

[image: Error seems to be from React Dev Tools extension in my case]

Comment: I tracked this issue down as it relates to the latest version of the React DevTools Chrome Extension.  The fix has still not been released at the time of my comment but it looks like they are working on it: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/20079

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to work with coco-ssd. I think this problem is caused by the version. I changed the version of tfjs to 0.9.0 and coco-ssd version to 1.1.0 and it worked for me. (You can search for posenet versions on *https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet*.)

```html
<!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.9.0"></script>
<!-- Load the coco-ssd model. -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd@1.1.0"</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it’s an error caused by [adblocker](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adblocker#Noun) extensions.

Make sure looking in another browser or disable extensions of this type.

Comment: I had this same issue. Nothing I was doing would fix it, and then I tried opening my web app in another chrome window under "guest" and it worked. I assume that the issue was caused by an extension on my primary chrome account.

Answer (score 1):

While [the fix as per Valeri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205390/when-adding-a-javascript-library-chrome-complains-about-a-missing-source-map-w/61611323#61611323) works, it’s only for tfjs.

If you're expecting for body-pix or any other TensorFlow or models, you would be facing the same. It is an open issue too and the team is working on the fix!

*[[extension] DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for browser-polyfill.js.map #1977](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/issues/1977)*

But, if you don't have a problem in degrading the version (if anyone wants to use body-pix) from [the latest documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix), both the below links works fine as I've tested the same:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/body-pix@1.0.0"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if it works in Incognito Mode. If it does, then it's a bug in recent Chrome. On my computer the following fix worked:

1. Quit Chrome
2. Delete your full Chrome cache folder
3. Restart Chrome

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the sourcemaps for *[node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* were explicitly excluded from processing. In my *webpack.config.js* I had to comment out the exclude option in module configuration (the `rules` part where `use: ["source-map-loader"]` is).

```
module: {
    rules:[
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            // exclude: /node_modules/, // This is the line that caused the problem. Remove or comment it out.
            enforce: "pre",
            use: ["source-map-loader"],
        },
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some broken URL was found in a layout.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? In its current form I don't think it is that useful.

Answer (score 0):

I get this warning in Angular if I run:

```
ng serve --sourceMap=false
```

To fix:

```
ng serve
```

Comment: What does it do (or is supposed to do)? Why does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can escape this by require your puppeteer from different environment.

- your_project (folder)
- - back_end modules (folder)
- - - vendor.js (require puppeteer here)
- - electron modules (folder)
- - - vendor.js (require vendor.js from back_end folder)
- main.js (electron main.js file) (require here vendor.js from electron modules folder)

Answer (score 0):

A rather trivial fix that doesn't require adjusting the browser settings at all is just to create file hammer.min.js.map in your Hammer folder and make its content an empty JSON object, that is, { }.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I ran into the same problem. The issue is due to the mapping. The url won't work entirely so you can just go to https://www.jsdelivr.com search for chartjs and copy the html code to use.
As of May 28, 2023 it's `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.3.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>`. Issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had some commented code in my main spring boot file, I deleted the code and then my pages loaded successfully.