# Due to nonexisting file, a waning message keeps popuping up

Tags: javascript, html, css, http-status-code-404

I have no idea why I get the warning message below.

DevTools failed to load SourceMap:

> Could not load content for
> http://localhost:8090/asset/css/sub.css.map: HTTP error: status code
> 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

I don't even have the file, sub.css.map. I have only sub.css.

Please help me get out of this rabbit hole..

Comment: please refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205390/devtools-failed-to-load-sourcemap-could-not-load-content

Comment: if it doesn't work please post [minimal reproduceable sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)