# Devtools are not loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, console, web-frontend

Im new to coding and have been learning html, css and js for some time and it's going great but for some reason whenever i use vsc and open the console on chrome i get two pop up messages in the console that are heiglighted in yellow saying "Devtools failed to load source map: could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net:: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT".

is it a serious problem that must be fixed, or should i just ignore it because the script is working fine.

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205390/how-can-i-fix-the-devtools-failed-to-load-sourcemap-could-not-load-content-er). You will probably find something there.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Go to Inspect → Settings (Symbol) gear → Uncheck Enable JavaScript source maps and Enable CSS source map.

Refresh.

(Note: Deactivate Adblock if the above process did not work.)