# devtools failed to parse sourcemap js popper js map in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, popper.js

In my browser console I am using AJAX request for getting an authentication token and redirect to my dashboard, but when I click to the login/sign-in button, nothing is happening. My link contains my email and password and my console generating an error:

> devtools failed to parse sourcemap js popper js map in asp.net mvc 5

I tried everything I can think of, including updating the browser and packages. Please can someone solve this problem

my login URL is Home/Login

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to add your well-formatted code. It makes diagnosis of a problem much more difficult if you only supply a picture of code, and it makes it much less likely that anyone will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see from your IDE screenshot, your `vendor/bootstrap/js` folder does not include `popper.js.map`, so when `popper.js` tries to load it, it fails, and throws the warning you reported here.

You can download the sourcemap file from the following URL:

https://unpkg.com/browse/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.js.map

Make sure to select the correct Popper.js version from the dropdown.

A better alternative would be to use a package manager, such as npm, NuGet, or Bower, since that's the preferred way to install the library.

```
npm i popper.js
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get rid of this warning (in google chrome) just do as follows:

F12: (Go to Developer Tools), then tick the box 'Selected context only'
[image]

Second, this warning is not related to your code (See a comprehensive description on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21719713/10703628)).