# Search Bar TypeError

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Good night everyone!

> TypeError Argument 2 passed to
> CodeIgniter\Database\BaseBuilder::like() must be of the type string,
> null given, called in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\lordeCI\app\Controllers\AutocompleteSearch.php on line
> 31

Codeigniter is throwing this error for the chunk of code below, '*titulo*' and '*post_id*'  are column names of a table called 'posts':

```
public function ajaxSearch()
    {
        helper(['form', 'url']);

        $data = [];

        $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
        $builder = $db->table('posts');   

        $query = $builder->like('titulo', $this->request->getVar('q')) //this is line 31
                    ->select('post_id, titulo as text')
                    ->limit(10)->get();
        $data = $query->getResult();
        
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Also, some images aren't loading properly, the browser gives a status code: 200 though content-type is "text/html", i've checked the image path and it is correct. However the message below showed up in dev tools, network tab.

> "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://pmncamalnkoafdfdmojmhanhngjaakcb/browser-polyfill.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For the exception

You are getting: You are passing empty value to the `q` param, the exception happens because it is like calling: `$query = $builder->like('titulo', null)`, this cannot happen, only strings are accepted as the second parameter for the `like` method.

To solve this, validate your parameter before using it:

```php
$titulo = '';
if ( ! empty( $titulo ) ) {
    $titulo = $this->request->getVar('q');
}
$query = $builder->like('titulo', $titulo);
```

A better way to do this is through [Form Validation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html).

#### The images problem

You must check how you are returning your images to your client. If you return a image directly from an `echo` you will have this kind of error.

Best way is to solve this in your app server level.

#### The SourceMap error

Not that big of a problem, this will not hinder your application in anything. Take a look at [this StackOverflow's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/how-to-use-javascript-source-maps-map-files).