# js - Do I Need to create a map file for minified files too?

Tags: javascript, minify

I am the author of [TreeJS](https://github.com/CoderNinja123/TreeJS). So far, I use TypeScript to generate the build file (plain browser-understandable JS), a Type Definitions file, and a map file for the **unminified** build. I use an external tool called [Minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify) to minify the build.

My question is, should I also create a map file for the minified build, or the map file for the unminified build will work with the minfied one?

And, If I do need to build a map for that, does anyone know any tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is *your* library, you don't need to do anything you don't want, but source maps can be huge help for your users. Minify uses terser to minify JavaScript, and [terser can generate composed source maps](https://terser.org/docs/cli-usage#composed-source-map). I never worked with Minify, but it seems like you can [pass map generated by typescript in options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify#user-content-options).

Comment: so is it better if I use **just** terser instead of Minify? BTW, thanks! I just googled up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21719713/14925444), and and by the looks I found out that source maps are used to **trace out the original .ts file (in my case)**. Thanks for your answer, otherwise I would have been stuck at the thought that maps are used to map out the **transpiled** files...

Comment: You can continue to use Minify, or use terser standalone, or not minify at all, if this is a library. Library will be minified anyway in target app via webpack or other bundler

Comment: Oh. But, I also want to target the non-bundling users; the ones who just want to load in the library into their HTML and do some stuff, so I thought to minify it. I think I'll switch to Terser indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. For direct usage you need to minify and and source maps.