# Getting warning because of missing .map file

Tags: javascript

I have included quill.min.js in my site (I have no reference to `quill.min.js.map` on my site)

[image]

When I debug the site, I see the following warning:

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> my-site/Scripts/quill.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404,
> net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

[image]

Why am I getting this warning? `quill.min.js.map` does not exists on my server, I have only included `quill.min.js`. Do I need to include the map file on the server too?

Is this line: `//# sourceMappingURL=quill.min.js.map` just a comment or a reference to the map file? if it's a comment, then I don't any reference to the map file on my site.

Comment: Before someone will flag and close this post, please replace images with actually code (text).
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Remove `//# sourceMappingURL=quill.min.js.map`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21719713/11151040

Comment: @BOZ: thanks so `//# sourceMappingURL=quill.min.js.map` is not a comment?

Comment: @ulou: the image is a minified library with thousands of characters... I cannot paste the whole library in the question.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini No, that's a comment. But inside the comment it is a readable variable. We can say that `# sourceMappingURL=` is detected by browsers. In short, if you are not in production or are using a library, you can clear this comment. The Warning it gives is not very important, but I don't know if it will technically affect performance. It is best to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `.map` file is just a "helper" for debugging. If you have a "minified" JS-file (which is mostly the case in production environments), the `.map` file, as the name says, maps it to a better human-readable version.

So, in short, there is no *need* to have that file on you production server and you can ignore the warning there. (Indeed having it in production should be avoided.) But it is helpful in development environments.

The `//# sourceMappingURL=quill.min.js.map` indeed is both a comment and additionally has an own semantic which is evaluated by a browser to indicate the path to the map file for debugging purposes. Nevertheless, you can (and, in this case, should) securely remove it.

Comment: Thanks, so `//# sourceMappingURL=quill.min.js.map` is not a comment, it's actually indicating that `quill.min.js.map` is the name of the map file?

Comment: Indeed, it's both, as also BOZ stated above. :) I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Chrome asks for a .map file for .min.js files if you have the DevTools (right click / Inspect or F12) tab open.