# How can I debug a xx.js file instead of a xx.min.js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a research on echarts' smooth line. So I want to go into echarts code and see how it is drawn.

I downloaded echarts source code from github, created a index.html, and add echarts.min.js to the script tag. The line chart is drawn successfully. However, when I open the chrome dev-tool to look into the code, I found that the code in the echarts.min.js is unreadable, beacuse it has been compressed. The name of variables and functions are replaced by letter sunch as `function ia(t, e, n, i, r)`, which I cannot understand.

What should I do to debug the sourcefile of the echarts.min.js?

[lineChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy1Ge.jpg)
[devtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkwgR.jpg)

Comment: If you want to read the source code, [go to the source](https://github.com/apache/echarts).

Comment: Thank you ,  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/how-can-i-use-javascript-source-maps-map-files) answers my question. I add a comment to the .min.js and I can see the source file in dev-tool.