# Rails 4 Error due to no favicon - How to disable this so i don't have to have a favicon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting this error due to not having a favicon: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):` but I don't want a favicon. How can I disable this so it stops looking for one?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests

Answer (score -1):

Only delete lines which include `favicon_link_tag` in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: I don't have a favicon_link_tag in any of my views.