# When uploading a file in recording mode in Jmeter receiving error

Tags: jmeter

I'm recording a file upload scenario in JMeter:

I have moved the required file to the bin folder of Apache JMeter(2.13 r1665067), but still when I am uploading the file I am getting the following error:

```
An error has occurred.[Webserver is crmdevextlnxvm10.extranet.hughes.com]
You may attempt to sign in again.
If your attempt fails, please contact your System Administrator.

ErrorTitle=

ErrorDescription=

ErrorURL=

AccessedURL=

OriginalURL=

TargetPage=

StackTrace=

DetailError=

Tue Aug 11 2015 18:37:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Sign in to PeopleSoft
```

What should I do ?

And, also in curiosity, when I'm trying to run the recorded scripts (even though I have received above error), I'm seeing an error in results tree for a `favicon.ico` request.

How can I make it run? Or can I exclude these requests?

Answer (score 0):

For favicon.ico - I'm used to removing this from recorded scripts. This should not affect your performance test results, but will make them clean.

Different browsers implement favicon handling different ways - [see e.g. here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_6.1.0/com.ibm.itame.doc_6.1/am61_webseal_admin138.htm%23favicon). Also this is a [good read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests). From JMeter perf testing point of view - favicon shouldn't be of your core interest.

Comment: Thank you. I will remove favicon from my request.
Also it would be helpful if I can get the answer for my first error, that is with  the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fiddler to see the http requests generated when uploading a file, instead of using Http(s) test script recorder. Then you can generate the requests in JMeter manually.