# PHP / MySQLi on Windows: inserts into a MySQL innoDB Table increases the AUTO_INCREMENT column by 2

Tags: php, mysqli

When I am doing a simple insert via the PHP `mysqli` API with prepared statements on Windows within a PHP process, the defined AUTO_INCREMENT column is increased by 2 instead of 1:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUES (?)
```

It get increased by 1 when doing multiple inserts (one by one in separate transactions) within one PHP process.

It always get increased by 1 when I use the same SQL query via phpmyadmin.

There are no other `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements before or after the mentioned `INSERT`. Only a `SHOW` and some `SELECT` statements before.

I cannot find the cause for this problem. What can be the causes for such a behaviour?

Here the main code parts:

```
<?php

class DB
{
    private function __construct($host, $username, $password, $schema, $port, $socket)
    {
        if(is_null(self::$DB))
        {
            self::$DB = new \MySQLi((string) $host, (string) $username, (string) $password, (string) $schema, (int) $port, (string) $socket);
            self::$DB->set_charset('utf8');

        }
    }
    // [...]
    public function __destruct()
    {
        if(!is_null(self::$DB))
            self::$DB->close();
    }
    // [...]
    public static function connect($host = '', $username = '', $password = '', $schema = '', $port = 0, $socket = '')
    {
        if(is_null(self::$instance))
        {
            $MD = new \MySQLi_driver();
            $MD->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT;
            // [...]
            self::$instance = new self($host, $username, $password, $schema, $port, $socket);
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
    // [...]
    public static function __callStatic($name, $args)
    {
        self::connect();

        switch(true)
        {
            case in_array($name, array('insert', 'select', 'update', 'delete', 'show', 'describe', 'explain')):

            $query = isset($args[0]) ? (string) $args[0] : '';
            $vals = isset($args[1]) ? $args[1] : array();
            $select = isset($args[2]) ? trim((string) $args[2]) : 'array';
            $empty = isset($args[3]) ? $args[3] : array();
            $types = isset($args[4]) ? trim((string) $args[4]) : '';

            return self::dml(in_array($name, array('show', 'describe', 'explain')) ? 'select' : $name, $query, $vals, $select, $empty, $types);

            break;
        }
    //[...]
    }

    // [...]
    public static function dml($type, $query, $vals = array(), $select = 'array', $empty = array(), $types = '')
    {
        // [...]
        if(!empty($vals) || mb_strpos($query,'?') !== false)
        {
            if(!$stmt = self::$DB->prepare($query))
                throw new DBException('Failed to prepare statement '.htmlspecialchars($query).PHP_EOL.self::$DB->error.' ('.self::$DB->sqlstate.').');

            $args = array();

            if(empty($types))
            {
                foreach($vals as &$val)
                {
                    $t = gettype($val);

                    if($t == 'string' || $t == 'NULL')
                        $types.= 's';
                    elseif($t == 'integer' || $t == 'boolean')
                        $types.= 'i';
                    elseif($t == 'double' || $t == 'float')
                        $types.= 'd';
                    else
                        throw new DBException('Its not possible to automatically assign a value of type '.$t.'. Please specify the corresponding types manually.');
                    $args[] = $val;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach($vals as &$val)
                    $args[] = $val;
            }

            array_unshift($args, $types);

            $RC = new \ReflectionClass($stmt);

            $RM = $RC->getMethod('bind_param');

            if(!$RM->invokeArgs($stmt, $args))
                throw new DBException('Failed to bind params.'.PHP_EOL.self::$DB->error.' ('.self::$DB->sqlstate.').');

            if(!$stmt->execute())
                throw new DBException('Failed to execute Statement.'.PHP_EOL.self::$DB->error.' ('.self::$DB->sqlstate.').');

            if($type == 'select')
            {
                // [...]
            }
            else
            {
                $return = $type == 'insert' && self::$DB->insert_id > 0 ? self::$DB->insert_id : self::$DB->affected_rows;
                $stmt->close();
                return $return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // [...]
        }
    }
}
?>
```

AND:

```
echo DB::insert("INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUES (?)", ["test"]);
```

The Query-Log shows 2 inserts. This causes the additional increment. But, when i put an echo into the corresponding DB::dml()-method, its only outputted once, thus called once. The mysql-query-log:

```
151026 12:54:49     3 Connect   XXX@localhost on XXX
 3 Query    SET NAMES utf8
        3 Query SELECT DATABASE() AS `schema`
        3 Query SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER
        3 Prepare   INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUES (?)
        3 Execute   INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUES ('testinsert22')
        3 Close stmt    
        3 Quit  
        4 Connect   XXX@localhost on XXX
        4 Query SET NAMES utf8
        4 Query SELECT DATABASE() AS `schema`
        4 Query SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER
        4 Prepare   INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUES (?)
        4 Execute   INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUES ('testinsert22')
        4 Close stmt    
        4 Quit
```

Comment: Please show us the full PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally got it.
The problem is: I redirect all requests to my index.php and do all the rest with PHP. I tested some classes behaviour with simple outputs. One of the tests lead to the problem above.
I checked the apache access log and noticed repeated favicon.ico requests. These requests - automatically produced by major browsers (see also [How to prevent favicon.ico requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests)) - also got to the index.php - and looks like some redirect to the browser?
normally this is all handled in my application framework, but i disabled it while i tested.