# I'm getting a 404 error message from an address not in my directory

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404, favicon

My server (Namecheap, Cpanel) is giving me the error in the title. It seems to be looking for http://www.efficientmind.org/favicon.ico .....but I haven't yet set up a favicon for the site... Also, this just popped up out of nowhere. I haven't seen this error yet and I haven't been doing any fiddling with setting up a favicon or that address in general. What could be causing this?

To remove hold status: I don't want my server to be checking for a favicon right now. I can see in the console that the server could not find it. This is especially confusing for me, a beginner, because I am also trying to solve a bug with the AJAX. I don't even know if the 2 issues could be potentially related, but I do want to learn how to stop the server from requesting a favicon (or where to simply place the folder for this and insert an image).

Comment: just add favicon icon and check if its working

Answer (score 1):

Browsers always look for favicon.ico in the root directory if you don't specify a favicon.

Answer (score 1):

A browser will, by default, look for it in the site’s root directory. So for http://www.google.com, that’s http://www.google.com/favicon.ico
However, its location can also be specified within the XHTML (of each page) by using one of the following :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/myicon.ico" />

<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://example.com/image.ico" />

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/image.png" />

<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://example.com/image.gif" />
```

[Referred From](http://techblog.wimgodden.be/2011/02/22/how-a-bad-favicon-ico-can-cause-a-lot-of-trouble/)

Refer- [How to prevent favicon.ico requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests)