# Python - Tornado : How to return 404 instead 500 for favicon

Tags: python, tornado, favicon, ico

Everytime i run my code in Chrome. It returns two request. Second is favicon.ico

But Favicon.ico's content type is text/html and status is 500

How can i change its status to 404

i dont have favicon.ico and i dont want to

[image]

Comment: 500 is server internal error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting 500, probably because `/favicon.ico` matches different route (e.g. with template without required params).

@Daniel B. answer is ok, (some) browsers won't request favicon - complete info can be found at [How to prevent favicon.ico requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests). Additionally I would add `ErrorHandler` route to server 404.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/favicon.ico", tornado.web.ErrorHandler, {'status_code': 404}),
        (r".*", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

There are also `apple-*ico` requested by Apple devices, you may want to send 404 as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This helps me a lot.Because if i dont have a html file and the answer below couldn't help me.Thanks again i wish i could upvote but i cant

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you get a 500, but if you don't want a favicon at all maybe you could add an empty one to your htmls head?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"type="image/x-icon" href="data:image/x-icon;,">
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont have a html file.Because i only render files with their mime types so no html.But thanks again