# history.pushState in Chrome make favicon request

Tags: javascript, html, favicon, pushstate

**Code :**

```
var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname +"?"+ queryStr; 
window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl)
```

**Current scenario :**

Every time when **`window.history.pushState()`** is invoked favicon requests occur rapidly.It makes network request for favicon on every call of this function.

**Expected scenario :**

The favicon should be loaded only once on page load, I would not expect the favicon load on every request of **`window.history.pushState()`**.

**Favicon paths are link like this in HTML page :**

```
<!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../img/icon/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../img/icon/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../img/icon/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a bug in `Chromium` browsers. See [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131567) open issue.

But there seems to be a workaround if you use `base64` image as `href` the request won't occur.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests) question.

Comment: In Chrome, when holding on the Back button, you get a list of all the links in history and you can choose one. The links have both icon and text. It only seems normal that the request for favico would be made when adding stuff to history. I wouldn't call it a bug.

Comment: Seems legit. I expressed my doubt in the answer `looks like a bug`, may not be, that's why it's open since 2012.

Comment: Thanks for the update..so there is any alternate solution for this problem.I don't want to load favicon on every call of window.history.pushState()

Comment: You can convert your icons to `base64` images and put it in `href` of `favicon` link.

Comment: @A_Singh, but there is no path of favicon in your answer..something like that `image.png`.

Comment: That's the trick "to not use" `image.png`, instead use `base64` image. If you don't know how to convert your image to one, see [this](https://www.base64-image.de/) website. Convert and put the output in `href` value. To read more about `base64 files` see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) wikipedia page.

Comment: Thanks..its working fine :) .. but i am getting very large string after convert image to base64..something like this..`data:image/png;base64,khjsfUYFDKJkfdskkiVBORw0KGgodfvjklsfksLDLDDK......`..is there any way to shorten this encoded string

Comment: This **string** is your image now, so it's gonna be large, you can't reduce the size without losing data. You can compress (`gzip` which I don't know much about) your image or reduce the resolution before encoding it into `base64`.  **More quality ~ Longer String** there's no going around it.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)