# Avoid using favicon

Tags: html

I don't have a favicon at the moment, so I want to make my website tab looking like this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Comment: What browser displays tabs like that...?

Comment: @txt Hmm, not mine, but okay...

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests) .. just add `<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=" />` to your `<head>` and the favicon icon will be blank (empty) .. additionally you can check out [this blog](https://davidwalsh.name/blank-favicon) that shows the `href` data for an actual blank image ... and @deceze, yeah, it's a modded theme (I happen to have the same theme setup)

Comment: @txt I'd file it as a bug with the theme author then...

Comment: Thanks @txtechhelp, problem solved. This is a duplicated question to [How to prevent favicon.ico requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you want to achieve is strictly possible. However, if you would like to only display your name why not add a transparent/empty favicon? You won't see some ugly default but it will instead be an invisble placeholder.