# Google App Engine: Disable favicon.ico

Tags: google-app-engine, favicon

I have a Google App Engine project running PHP 5.5. This is my `app.yaml`:

```
application: example
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.php
```

All requests go to `main.php`. My app only sends data for an Android application and thus doesn't need to display a `favicon.ico`. But if I call my application in my browser (Chrome) and consult the app logs afterwards there is a request to `favicon.ico`. How can I disable this or how can I tell App Engine to **NOT SERVE** a favicon?

**EDIT**: I can't just send some HTML to prevent the loading of the favicon, because I need to send JSON data to my application in which I can't include HTML.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests

Comment: Please read the text I've added (under **EDIT**)

Comment: No, I just see them when using Chrome. So is it Chomes fault?

Comment: It's not a "fault" of Chrome but yeah, Chrome is responsible for making that request (as would any other modern browser) so there's nothing to disable. If a 404 is bothering you in the logs - just create a small `favicon.ico` file to be served for the rare cases when you open your app in a browser.