# Can I block a favicon?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any possibility using javascript to block the favicon of a webpage ?

I can change it, but I'm not able to find a way to block the original one. Is it possible ?

I tried this, without success :

```
var newLink = document.createElement("link");
newLink.setAttribute("rel", "icon");
newLink.setAttribute("href", "###");
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(newLink);
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Do you mean remove the favicon?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests

Comment: Also refer this
http://lifehacker.com/5036881/how-to-block-distracting-animated-favicons

Comment: So you want an adblocker for favicons...?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I dont think you need to block the favicon....and you can block it in your browser settings

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can delete the favicon from your own webpage by simply removing or renaming it..

I don't think it is possible to have favicons blocked from other websites and why would you want that?