# How to findout more about 404 error from Github pages?

Tags: fiddler, github-pages

I have created a simple web page on GitHub and [here](https://infosecureit.github.io/) is the url. I am now using fiddler to load it, and every time I load the page, I get a 404 error as well as a successful connection and download of the page, and I do not know why I get the 404 error. When I am logged into GitHub, and click on the clone button of my repo, the url is: `https://github.com/InfosecureIT/InfosecureIT.github.io.git`
How can I know what file the GitHub server is referring to when it says file can not be found?

@ jpvillaisaza - Sure, the error is 404 file not found. [image: here] is a picture, which would describe the error better.

Comment: Can you add the error that you get? Is it related to a missing favicon.ico?

Comment: Thanks. The image is not showing the complete error, but it is about the missing favicon, so I added an answer that might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is related to a missing `favicon.ico` file. Even though your HTML code doesn't specify a favicon, browsers can request it and display an error. This shouldn't be a problem with loading everything else, but you might want to either add a favicon picture, which will probably be better for your site, or find a way to avoid the favicon request (see [How to prevent favicon.ico requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1321878/2102854), for example).